# nagios/icinga logwarn plugin

Tags: plugins, nagios, error-logging

I'm using Icinga and [logworn](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Log-Files/check_logwarn/details) for finding "ERROR" in the tomcat logs. The problam is that when it founds an error it marks it as warnning and not error. 
I followed this [tutorial](http://linuxdrops.com/how-to-monitor-log-files-using-nagios-or-icinga/). I get this message: `Log errors: 13:31:47,092 ERROR [LoggingAspect] Unhandled exception caught: com.xxx.filter.AuthenticationProvider  authenticat` 
Can I change it to return an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are log errors matched, the plugin returns WARNING to Nagios. If you want it to return ERROR just edit the last line of the script. (change to STATE_CRITICAL='2')

Answer (score 0):

I recommend labs.consol.de/nagios/check_logfiles/
check_logfiles --criticalpattern "ERROR" --logfile .../tomcat.log